# Changing the color of one TStatusPanel after initial program load in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, colors, c++builder, statusbar, ondraw

I've got a program with a status bar at the bottom containing three elements. I'd like to redraw the second element in a different font color to signify that a user is valid. The first part of my question is:

a) How can I redraw the text in a different color to the default text?

and b) How can I draw the text in a different color after an event is triggered (For example a button push)?

My current code is below. I'm trying to check whether the condition for the panel to be repainted in a different color is correct (CurrentUser.Valid, which is a boolean), and then trying to recolor the text. This currently does not work.

```
procedure TChatFormMain.sbarMainDrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
var
  RectForText: TRect;
begin
  if (Panel = StatusBar.Panels[1]) and (CurrentUser.Valid) then
  begin
    sbarMain.Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
    RectForText := Rect;
    StatusBar.Canvas.FillRect(RectForText);
    DrawText(sbarMain.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Panel.Text), -1, RectForText,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT);
  end;
end;
```

In another part of the code I'm calling `StatusBar.repaint;` to try and redraw the bar with the new text colour, is this correct?

Update MCVE:

```
unit colourStatusU;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel;
      const Rect: TRect);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  valid : boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  valid := true;
  StatusBar1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel;
  const Rect: TRect);
var
  RectForText: TRect;
begin
  if (Panel = StatusBar.Panels[1]) and (Valid) then
  begin
    Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
    RectForText := Rect;
    Canvas.FillRect(RectForText);
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Panel.Text), -1, RectForText,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: maybe you just did not set the style of your second panel to psOwnerDraw

Comment: ..well now I feel stupid. It now draws the text, but it's all the way up at the top of the form instead of inside the panel.

Comment: `DrawText(StatusBar.Canvas.Handle ...` and `StatusBar.Canvas.Font.` make you own answer to the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `OnDrawPanel` event is called only for a panel that has its `Style` set to `psOwnerDraw`, so make sure you have set the `Style` properly, either in the Object Inspector or in code.

The `Canvas` to paint on must be the `TStatusBar.Canvas`, but you are using the `TForm.Canvas` instead.  Use the `Canvas` of the `StatusBar` that is provided by the `OnDrawPanel` event:

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel;
  const Rect: TRect);
var
  RectForText: TRect;
begin
  if (Panel = StatusBar.Panels[1]) and (Valid) then
  begin
    StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
    RectForText := Rect;
    StatusBar.Canvas.FillRect(RectForText);
    DrawText(StatusBar.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Panel.Text), -1, RectForText, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT);
  end;
end;
```

Calling `Repaint()` or `Invalidate()` to force the Statusbar to *refesh* its painting is the method to use.